# ¿Como obtener el valor seleccionado de un SELECT en Angular 4?

Tags: angular

Estoy iniciando en el framework Angular 4, y tengo una duda respecto al Select,
Necesito saber que opción selecciona el usuario de mi Select.

En mi *App.component.html* tengo este codigo :

```
<select name="" id="cantidad" (change)="capturar()">
  <option *ngFor="let dato of datos">
    {{dato}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Y en mi *app.component.ts* tengo este :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  datos;
  constructor(){
    this.datos=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
  }
  capturar(){

  }
}
```

Comment: y el controller donde quedo?

Comment: Esa es una Excelente pregunta, ya que nunca he visto que se use un controller con Angular4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estabas muy cerca, tienes que usar la directiva [`(ngModel)`](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) para a poder obtener el valor del `<select>`:

<kbd>[Ver Demo Online](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dsrx92?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)</kbd>

```
<select [(ngModel)]="opcionSeleccionado" (change)="capturar()">
    <option value="0">Selecciona una opción</option>
    <option *ngFor="let dato of datos">
      {{dato}}
    </option>
</select>

<!-- Prueba para ver la opción seleccionado -->
<p [hidden]="opcionSeleccionado == '0'">Haz seleccionado la opción # {{ verSeleccion }}</p>
```

```
export class AppComponent  {
  datos;
  // Seleccionamos o iniciamos el valor '0' del <select>
  opcionSeleccionado: string  = '0';
  verSeleccion: string        = '';

  constructor(){
      this.datos = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
  }  

  capturar() {
      // Pasamos el valor seleccionado a la variable verSeleccion
      this.verSeleccion = this.opcionSeleccionado;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Estas son las dos maneras que mas recomienda Angular en su documentación Reactive forms o Template-driven forms.

**Ejemplo con Reactive forms.**

**componen.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="paisFormulario">
    <select id="pais" formControlName="pais">
        <option *ngFor="let p of paises" [ngValue]="p">{{ p }}</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

**component.ts**

```
        import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

            export class Component {

                paises: string[] = ['Mexico', 'España', 'Venezuela'];
                default: string = 'Mexico';

                paisFormulario: FormGroup;

                constructor() {
                    this.paisFormulario = new FormGroup({
                        pais: new FormControl(null)
                    });
                 // setValue es para agregarle un valor
                    this.paisFormulario.controls['pais'].setValue(this.default, 
 {onlySelf: true});
                // para obtenerlo necesitarias un get por ejemplo
              this.paisFormulario.get('pais');
                }
            }
```

**Template-driven forms**

Es el ejemplo que puso Black Sheep Template-driven forms es un  los dos te pueden servir espero y te ayuden.

Puedes leer mas de eso en https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview